# AWS storage class analysis vs intelligent tiering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I understand that AWS storage class analysis allows us to  understand the access pattern of object, which can then be used to make decision on life cycle policy configuration

With S3 Intelligent Tiering, why do we need to use this approach? Isn't Intelligent tiering a solution that can get rid of storage class analysis and hassle of setting up life cycle policy configuration? (Apart from probably cost as I understand that other than same cost for storage by class, Intelligent tiering charge an extra of "All Storage / Month   $0.0025 per 1,000 objects" for Monitoring and Automation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a great explanation from https://www.1strategy.com/blog/2019/09/25/s3-intelligent-tiering-vs-lifecycle-configuration/

The answer is that it depends on the situation. As both approach charges differently. Apart from storage cost, both would encounter cost as:

- S3 Intelligent tiering approach - additional charges of "All Storage / Month $0.0025 per 1,000 objects for Monitoring and Automation"
- Storage class analysis + lifecycle configuration approach - Analytics cost $0.10 per million objects monitored per month + Storage cost of files produced by S3 Inventory and S3 Storage Class Analysis (exports are stored in your specified S3 bucket, and are subject to S3 Standard storage charges)+ manhours for manual analysis and configs

If objects have a "defined lifecycle, such as needing frequent access for a month and then never needing to be accessed again, a lifecycle policy is the most efficient and cost-effective solution for you."

And for "access patterns are unpredictable or difficult to identify, Intelligent Tiering is an excellent solution for hands-off storage access monitoring while still taking advantage of cost savings from S3-IA."

Also note: S3-Intelligent Tiering supports lifecycle policies, so you could even configure rules to keep objects in Intelligent Tiering for a few months, and then move them to S3-Glacier.